# how to write $_POST method for each text input

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a bunch on table rows where each row will contain a bunch text inputs. Now below is the name attributes for the possible inputs which contains its own value in each table row:

```
answerAvalue = A
answerBvalue = B
answerCvalue = C
answerDvalue = D
answerEvalue = E

... //all the way to answerZvalue = Z

answerTruevalue = True
answerFalsevalue = False
answerYesValue = Yes
answerNovalue = No
```

Each table row also contains some radio buttons which are below:

```
<input type="radio" name="reply" />= = Single
<input type="radio" name="reply" />= = Multiple
```

So lets say I go through each table row and retrieve the values of each radio button selected in each row, then the code for this is below:

```
$i = 0;
$c = count($_POST['gridValues']); //counts number of appended rows

for($i = 0;  $i < $c; $i++ ){ //for each loop which goes through each row

switch ($_POST['reply'][$i]){ 

case "single": 
$selected_reply = "Single"; 
break; 

case "multiple": 
$selected_reply = "Multiple"; 
break; 

default: 
$selected_reply = ""; 
break; 

}
```

But what my question is that because each text input has its own name attribute, then how can I write the code to achieve the same as above but for obviously for the text inputs?

Comment: First of all by indenting your code. And as far as forms are concerned, the logic to read the input is always connected to the logic to generate the form fields.

Comment: Take a look at naming your variables with a convention like `<input name="textvalue[answerA]" />`, `<input name="textvalue[answerB]" />`, ... and then looping over the `$_POST["textvalue"]` array

Comment: The textinput looks like this: `var input = '<input type="text" id="' + hid + '" value="' + value + '" name="' + id + 'value" />';` Are you saying I need to change it to this: `var input = '<input type="text" id="' + hid + '" value="' + value + '" name="value ' + id + '" />';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
echo $key."=>".$value; //key is for example "reply" and value f.e. "2"
```

Comment: So is the code above simply stating post everything using just $_POST e.g. reply radio buttons, text input values etc

Comment: all form fileds that were posted with the form

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value)
{
  if(is_array($value))
  {
     foreach($value as $k => $v)
     {
       echo k."=>".$v; 
     }
  }
  else
  {
     echo $key."=>".$value; 
  }
}
```